# clear Ubuntu One (Web) Contacts Overview

Tags: ubuntu-one, contacts, cleanup

Is there a way to clear the log on Ubuntu One (web) about your Contacts Overview like recently added, removed, ect.?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Some obscure privacy reason?